# Docusign: how to make envelope recipient to sign two documents at different times?

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I'm using docusign for electronic signatures. My workflow can be simplified as follow:

- there are two signers (**S1** and **S2**) and 2 documents (**D1** and **D2**)
- **S1** need to sign **D1** (but he shall not see **D2**)
- then actions are taken in real life...
- then **S2** sign both documents
- and **S1** finally needs to sign **D2**

I have tried with documentVisibility, [but the doc says](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocumentvisibility/update/):

> A document cannot be hidden from a recipient if the recipient has tabs assigned to them...

What is the best way to achieve such a workflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you need are 3 signers - S1, S2, and S3. S3 is similar to S1 but is technically a different signer in the system. So you can restrict S1 from viewing D2 because only S2 and S3 have tabs in that document.
If this doesn't work then are two alternative ways to do that:

**Option 1 - two envelopes.**

In this option you create a new envelope based on the complete docs from the first envelope and send this second document for D2 to sign. It would do what you want. It just that it will require two separate envelopes.

**Option 2 - correcting an envelope.**

In that option you add D2 after S1 signs and add S1 as a signer in the last position (routing order) after S2. So the envelope has to be modified mid-way using the Correct flow.

Comment: Just a note: **it is impossible to have multiple signer with same name per envelope** thus your first solution is not really viable unless you can have different names. Also creating  evelopes can only be done at additional cost. Could you give more details on third option please ? Thx for such details and quick response however :)

Comment: That's incorrect. You can do that if they have differed routing order. Please let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: My bad, I shall have missed something, a link to the doc about routing order could be useful in your answer, I don't find relevant information online :)

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-signing-order